# Java Swing : get index of combobox inside table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I need to have combo boxes (`JComboBox`) in the first column of `JTable`.

```
    JTable table = new JTable(5,10);
    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Now, how can I get selected index of combo box in a certain cell ?

`table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0)` returns a String. That's not what I need.

Comment: why .......................

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use checkbox.getSelectedIndex()? If you declare checkbox in different cells they will all contain a copy of the same. So if you want different comboboxes in different cells you should declare them all with different names. And then you get the selected index like I said before.

Comment: So is setting cell editor to each cell (not the whole column) is the only way to get its indexes ?

Comment: The point is if you have innumerous comboboxes with the same model which they will because they are copies, the selected index will always be the same. So either you create a differente model for eacho combobox or create innumerous comboboxes and get the selected index by its name.

Comment: typically, there is absolutely no need to directly access the editing component ... most probably there's something wrong with the OP's context/understanding/assumed solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way all this works under the covers is that the `JComboBox` is treated as a simple delegate editor and the value of the `JComboBox` is what's kept in the table, not the `JComboBox` instance (otherwise you'd need an instance per cell). (You can read the [gory details in the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.java#DefaultCellEditor.%3Cinit%3E%28javax.swing.JComboBox%29))

What this means is that all that's available to you from the `JTable` is the currently selected value, which will be of type of the parameterized type `E` in `JComboBox<E>`, in your case, evidently, a `String`.

If you want to get the index of a particular value, you need to pull it using the `ComboBoxModel<E>` backing your `JComboBox<E>` -- if you've implemented your own `ComboBoxModel<E>` you'll have to implement your own method, but assuming you've used the default ([`DefaultComboBoxModel<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html)), you can do something like:

```
int index = ((DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) comboBox.getModel()).getIndexOf(value)
```

Comment: this question isn't answerable, without an SSCCE and with detgailed desription, `see e.g. table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0) returns a String. That's not what I need.` maybe s/he has Boolean, Double, Color or Icon ias Items stored in XxxComboBoxModel, but without override getColumnClass (corresponding data type as for XxxComboBoxModel) is return value in String by deafult

Comment: @mKorbel: I wouldn't have answered the question unless I thought in answerable (and my reputation here might suggest I know something about that). In particular, this addresses "how do I get selected index of combo box for certain cell?" and clearly states assumptions. My answer also addresses the case where DefaultComboBoxModel is not used. Your feedback that the OP's question is poor would be better directed at the OP, as your cryptic comment "why?" does little to help the OP understand how to improve his/ her question.

Comment: "how do I get selected index of combo box for certain cell?" from editor by using ListSelectionListener, otherwise from XxxTableModel